# How should a renewal NSF proposal be prepared differently?

Tags: funding, nsf

What NSF's guideline (PAPPG) says about (traditional) renewal proposals is that they...

> ...must be developed as fully as though the proposer is applying for the first time.

Should there some special consideration for renewal proposals?

Comment: What special consideration might there be other than following that guideline? Of course the renewal proposal will refer to the original and to what came out of it.

Comment: Unlike NIH, NSF does not consider projects "renewable". You have to propose a new project. This new project may of course be based on a previous one, but the issue is that NSF does not treat such proposals any differently than de novo submissions.